# Sql server does allow to insert a row into a table, but does not allow to delete or update it

Tags: sql-server-2008, delete-row

I have a table named Project, it has single primary index named Project_Id. Primary index also has IDENTITY specification.
I can freely insert new row into the Project table, but then I cannot edit it, nor delete it. Here is the error it shows after the attempts:
[image]

Here is my data from the table:[image]

I want to delete those rows with id=17, 18, 19, 20. But I can't. Please also notice that I have no other table in my DB that references those id's in Project table, so I should be able to delete rows. 
 Any soughts about this? Do I need to provide more information for you to be able to pinpoint solution? Here is my relations diagram (a bit big, but anyway here it is):[image]

Just found out, that I can't update\delete rows even in Orders table (look right and up at diagram). I'm curious why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if the error message is a red herring and this is actually a permissions issue. Can you update or delete rows in any table? Have you checked the permissions for the database user ?

Comment: I just retried all tables, here is list of tables that I cannot edit: Customer, Orders, Projects. Also I login throught windows authentification. I also have created the tables by muselfs, so there shouldn't be any permissions cases for my DB.

Comment: Are you getting this error via the data editor or are you running a query? Do both give the same results?

Comment: What results do you get when querying syscolumns for this table?

Comment: http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/6296/sqlcols.jpg - this is for Project table. Should I select more fields?

Comment: I just go to recteate tables with different names and they seems to work fine.... have no idea why the error happed... but hey, thank for your tries!